# How to set priority correctly in Arena simulation

Tags: arena-simulation

I am working in the Arena Simulation program and I need help. I saw your videos on YouTube, but they did not give me a complete understanding of how to properly work with this program.
I do not understand how to correctly set the priority in the Queue module(Highest and Lowest Attribute Value), I have 120 combinations from 1-2-3-4-5 to 5-4-3-2-1 and I need to somehow set the priority correctly in the Queue module, not please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time but for those interested in the question:

Let's go through the emergency room example. Let's say you want to prioritize critically ill patients.
First, we can assign a value of "1" to critically ill patients using the assign module.(attribute)
Basic Process-> Queue -> Type -> highest attribute value
Thus, critically ill patients can enter the queue first.

Apart from this, other sorting types can also be used. (FIFO, LIFO, LVF, HVF)

For process to priority,
There are three options. High, Medium and Low. If one source will perform more than one operation, processes can also be given priority.